# Download a MemoryStream txt file from a blazor page

Tags: c#, blazor

I am writing a small demo test program that converts image files to ascii art (text files). I have tested the application in console mode and now I want to put it on a web page. In the following code, the image is uploaded and transformed to a MemoryStream that represents the ascii art (txt file), the problem I am facing is how to download the file without creating a temporary file on the disk of the server. I know that a get request can do that, but how I pass the MemoryStream to a get api (it can be a big file) I also heard about using a javascript function using JSRuntime to invoke it, but i have no a clue any help is appreciate.

```
@page "/"
@using ClassLibraryTransformImageToAsciiArt;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms

@inject IConvertImageToAsciiArt ConvertImageToAsciiArt
@inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime

<div class="container">
    <h1>Transform Images To Ascii Art</h1>
    <InputFile OnChange="@OnInputFileChange" />
</div>

@code {
    private long maxFileSize = 1024L * 1024L * 10L; //10 Mb

    private async Task OnInputFileChange(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        MemoryStream imageStream = new MemoryStream();
        await e.File.OpenReadStream(maxAllowedSize: maxFileSize).CopyToAsync(imageStream);
        MemoryStream textFileStream = ConvertImageToAsciiArt.ConvertImageToAsciiArtStream(imageStream);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to reset the stream position `imageStream.Position = 0;` although I'm not sure why you needed to use it anyway, you could have just pass the file directly `ConvertImageToAsciiArt.ConvertImageToAsciiArtStream(e.File.OpenReadStream(maxAllowedSize: maxFileSize))`

Comment: Did you check the https://github.com/arivera12/BlazorDownloadFile nuget ? I'm using it and it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Well after a lot of searching ChatGpt help me this time. I used a javascript function

```
@page "/"
@using ClassLibraryTransformImageToAsciiArt;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms

@inject IConvertImageToAsciiArt ConvertImageToAsciiArt
@inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime

<div class="container">
    <h1>Transform Images To Ascii Art</h1>
    <InputFile OnChange="@OnInputFileChange" />
</div>

@code {
    private long maxFileSize = 1024L * 1024L * 10L; //10 Mb

    private async Task OnInputFileChange(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        MemoryStream imageStream = new MemoryStream();
        await e.File.OpenReadStream(maxAllowedSize: maxFileSize).CopyToAsync(imageStream);
        MemoryStream textFileStream = ConvertImageToAsciiArt.ConvertImageToAsciiArtStream(imageStream);
        // download the file
        byte[] data = textFileStream.ToArray();
        string fileName = e.File.Name + ".txt";
        await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("downloadFile", fileName, data);
    }
}
```

And the javascript function

```
downloadFile = (fileName, data) => {
    const blob = new Blob([data], { type: "text/plain" });

    // Crea un enlace de descarga
    const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    downloadLink.download = fileName;

    // Simula un clic en el enlace para descargar el archivo
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    downloadLink.click();
    document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
};
```